# Error in while running the android app

Tags: android

I got the following error in my emulator while running the my android app.

The application "myapplication name" on a phone(process com.dummies.android.myappname) has stopped unexpectly. Please try agaign

please help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Please put your tracelogs Sunitha, you will find them in DDMS under logs

Comment: Yes, without concrete error from logcat we have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not helpful ( it just says that the application has crashed ). To get the full trace, you can use Android Debug Bridge ( adb ) which is included in your sdk.
( the default command for checking logs is "adb logcat" )

for more information about adb, you can check http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html